# Are all the Ultegra brake pads the same?

Tags: carbon, brake-pads, brake-noise, shimano-di2

I have a road bike with Shimano Ultegra Di2 6870 goupset. Today it was my first long ride with it and alsmost instantly I noticed that the brake pads are not for carbon rims. I tried searching on the internet brake pads for ultegra 6870 but with no luck. Are other ultegra brake pads compatible with my brakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Shimano groupset page](http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/road/ultegra_di20.html), both brake options for the Ultegra Di2 6870 groupset (BR-6800, BR-6810) ship with the Shimano R55C4 pads, which are designed for carbon rims.

So more than likely, either the brakes are not setup correctly, or the Shimano pads suck.

Comment: Well this morning it was my second time using the bike after the triathlon and it's making a horrible loud noise every time I brake, is that normal maybe at the beginning? because I read somewhere that is a sign that the pads are not for carbon.

Comment: Is there crud in the pads? Did you replace the original pads? If so, you may have put non-carbon pads on.

Comment: I just read in Wiggle: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-br9000-r55c4-cartridge-inserts-pair/ "Pad compound formulated for use with standard alloy rim braking surface"

Comment: Looks like theres a Carbon (http://www.evanscycles.com/products/shimano/dura-ace-9000-r55c4-carbon-cartridge-brake-pads-ec057594) and non-Carbon version, so it seems like it might ship with the non-Carbon type.

Comment: thanks @Batman, you are right they have for versions.. I bought this on eBay because I need to change the 4 of them.. http://ebay.eu/1yhmYCV

Answer (score 2):

If you have carbon rims (with a carbon braking surface) you will need appropriate brake pads, so as not to damage the rims.  You do not have to use shimano brake shoes- most (possibly all?) rim brakes will take any brand of shoes.

There is a [carbon rim insert](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-dura-ace-90009010-inserts-for-carbon-rims-pair/) for Dura Ace, which might fit the ultegra shoes.  However if there are no compatible pads for your brake shoes/ rims, you may have to buy a new set of shoes - not especially pricy, and they will come with pads.